# Crystal lattice structure from single crystal x-ray diffraction pattern

Tags: crystal-structure, crystallography, x-ray-diffraction, bravais-lattices

Is there a good reference describing the inverse problem of determining the crystal lattice, unit cell etc., from a single crystal x-ray diffraction pattern and chemical composition? I am looking for one that goes into details on how the fourier transforms are used, how the atomic numbers are used etc. Any sort of publication/book/lecture notes/video will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Here is a start: https://youtu.be/9n1u8ymc8aw?feature=shared

Comment: And here a more comprehensive source: https://global.oup.com/academic/product/fundamentals-of-crystallography-9780199573653?cc=us&lang=en&

Comment: G. Rhodes 'Crystallography made crystal clear- a guide for users of macromolecular models' (publ AP 2006), D. McKie & C. McKie, 'Essentials of Crystallography'  (publ.  Blackwell 1992 ), C. Hammond, 'The basics of Crystallography and Diffraction' (OUP 2003) ,  R. James ' The optical principles of the Diffraction of X-rays' (publ Bell & Sons 1965) Classic text, v thorough.

Comment: Thank you, @porphyrin and @Karsten!